# PyGithub - How to get a list of all commits for a particular branch?

Tags: github-api, pygithub

I need to check all commits made to a particular branch on github.

I am aware of

```
repo.get_commits()
```

but this returns commits for all branches of that repository I guess. I haven't found any branch attribute neither in [Commit class](https://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/github_objects/Commit.html#github.Commit.Commit)  nor in [Gitcommit class](https://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/github_objects/GitCommit.html#github.GitCommit.GitCommit).

Also there is not sth like .get_commits() in [Branch class](https://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/github_objects/Branch.html#github.Branch.Branch)

What is the proper way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [discussed here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212499/discussion-between-poseidonius-and-yazou), this should utimately use the [GitHub API List Commits](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#list-commits)

```
get /repos/{owner}/{repo}/commits
```

With as parameter the sha or branch name from which you want to list commits.

Ib PyGitHub, that is [`github.Repository.Repository.get_commits()`](https://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/github_objects/Repository.html?highlight=get_commits#github.Repository.Repository.get_commits), with `sha – string` being the name of the branch.

That will return a [`github.PaginatedList.PaginatedList`](https://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/utilities.html#github.PaginatedList.PaginatedList) of [`github.Commit.Commit`](https://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/github_objects/Commit.html#github.Commit.Commit)

Comment: Actually the link for the discussion does not work for me but your answer is complete so I actually do not need it anymore. Thanks